# How to find an appropriate sample size given information about the CV?

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem

> You are planning to collect a (simple random) sample to estimate the mean of a non-negative random variable. It is known that the population coefficient of variation (CV) is 1.2. Use the central limit theorem to determine (approximately) the smallest sample size needed so that you will be at least 98% confident that the sample mean is within 5% of the population mean.

Just wondering if my steps below are right or not?
First, I carry out this step to get the following equation

$$P\left(0.95\mu \le \bar{x}\le 1.05\mu \right)\:=\:1\:-\:2P\left(Z\le -0.041667\sqrt{n}\right)$$

After which, I solve for n by this

$$1\:-\:2P\left(Z\le -0.041667\sqrt{n}\right)\ge 0.95.$$

Am I doing it the right way?

Also, I would like to know if it is possible to just use the formula : 
$n=\frac{\left(c^2\cdot z^2\right)}{ME^2}, c=1.2, z=2.325, ME=0.05$?

Thank you so much for your time and help!